# OpenCL Kernel not compiling?

Tags: opencl

Following is my kernel:

```
#ifdef FP64

#ifdef cl_khr_fp64 //Khronos extension available
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
#define DOUBLE_SUPPORT_AVAILABLE

#elif defined(cl_amd_fp64) //AMD extension available
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_fp64 : enable
#define DOUBLE_SUPPORT_AVAILABLE
#endif

#endif

#ifdef DOUBLE_SUPPORT_AVAILABLE

//double
typedef double myreal;

#else

//float
typedef float myreal;

#endif

__kernel void calcURatios(__global myreal *ratios, __global myreal *rhs, __local myreal *lRatios, __local myreal *lRhs, myreal c, myreal r)
{
    size_t gid = get_global_id(0);
    size_t lid = get_local_id(0);

    lRatios[lid] = ratios[gid];
    lRhs[lid] = rhs[gid];

    lRatios[lid] = lRatios[lid] / c;
    ratios[gid] = lRatios[lid];

    lRatios[lid] = lRatios[lid] * r;
    lRhs[lid] = lRhs[lid] - lRatios[lid];
    rhs[gid] = lRhs[lid];
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\OCL2AD4.tmp.cl(1): error: expected an
          identifier
  #ifdef(FP64)
        ^

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\OCL2AD4.tmp.cl(30): error: expected an
          identifier
  #ifdef
        ^

2 errors detected in the compilation of "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\OCL2AD4.tmp.cl".

Internal error: clc compiler invocation failed.
```

I even tried with #ifdef(FP64) but still it gave me the same error.
I am unable to understand what is the problem?

Comment: Compiles for me. What OpenCL platform are you using? Maybe it's worth submitting the bug?

Comment: I am using APP SDK on Windows7. I tried on ATI GPU as well as Intel CPU. Getting the same error for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text being read from the .cl file was replacing every white space with `\n`. Hence the code being passed to the OpenCL compiler was something like this:

```
#ifdef
FP_64
#ifdef
cl_khr_fp64
....
```

The problem is resolved after adding spaces instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Check double data type support oh Host side & pass macro `myreal` when building program:

```
cl_uint native_double_width;    
clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE, sizeof(cl_uint), &native_double_width, NULL);

if(native_double_width){
    clBuildProgramm(...,"-D myreal=double",...);
}
else{
    clBuildProgramm(...,"-D myreal=float",...);
}
```

Then use macro (not typedef in this case) in your kernel.